# Google maps directions and area near route

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, area, google-directions-api

How I can do something like here in image with google map, Is anybody know ho to do this.

So here is directions and area near route directions (green opacity area)

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would approach this by using the [Directions API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/directions/#Routes) and getting lat/lng of each `step`.

I would then use the [Polygons API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/model/Circle) to draw circles of a chosen radius, every x meters along a straight path following the `steps`.

EDIT:

A better solution would be to use the `steps` with a [`Polyline`](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/overlays), and give it a sufficiently thick `strokeWidth`

Comment: hm, I dont know is it posible, I belive that there is not used polygons circles ...

Comment: maybe if I draw it every 10m but how many request then I need to use for distance etc. 100km :)

Comment: Ah yeah, a better solution would be to use a [Polyline](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/overlays) and give it a thick stroke width, with all the lat/lng of the steps as the input.